# Moq C# MongoDB FindAsync return value

Tags: c#, mongodb, moq, xunit.net

Recently we implemented a generic version of a repository for Mongo.

**Repository**

```
public async Task<IList<T>> FindAsync<T>(FilterDefinition<T> t) where T : IMongoModel
{
    var collection = _connection.GetCollection<T>();
    var result = await collection.FindAsync<T>(t);
    return await result.ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IList<T>> FindAsync<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter) where T : IMongoModel
{
    var collection = _connection.GetCollection<T>();
    var result = await collection.FindAsync(filter);
    return await result.ToListAsync();
}
```

**Code Being Called**

```
private async Task<MongoDb.Advertisement.Service.Models.AdvertisementFiles.Advertisement> DealerZipCodeAndLocation(MongoDb.Advertisement.Service.Models.AdvertisementFiles.Advertisement advertisement, string searchPhone)
{
    var matchingDealers = await _mongoRepository.FindAsync(Builders<Dealer>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.Phones, z => z.PhoneNumber == searchPhone));
    if (!matchingDealers.Any())
    {
        return advertisement;
    }
    if (matchingDealers.Count > 1)
    {
        _logger.Warning("More than one dealer found with {PhoneNumber}", searchPhone);
    }
    var matchingDealer = matchingDealers.FirstOrDefault();
    if (matchingDealer.Geocode == null)
    {
        var geoCode = await _geoLocationCache.GetGeocodByZipCode(matchingDealer.Address.ZipCode);

        if (geoCode.status != "OK")
        {
            return advertisement;
        }
        advertisement.Geocode = geoCode;
        advertisement.ZipCode = matchingDealer.Address.ZipCode;
        await UpdateGeocode<Dealer>(matchingDealer.Id, geoCode);
    }

    return advertisement;
}
```

**Have also tried following signatures**

```
var matchingDealers = await _mongoRepository.FindAsync<Dealer>(x => x.Phones.Any(y => y.PhoneNumber == searchPhone));
var matchingDealers = await _mongoRepository.FindAsync(filter);
```

When mocking out the FindAsync call, I am having difficulty with the return.  The issue is either with the signature not matching, or more likely with async.

**Moq Setup**
I have tried both versions (also with `It.IsAny<string>()` in place of the phone number)

```
_testFixture.MongoRepository.Setup(x => x.FindAsync(Builders<Dealer>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.Phones, z => z.PhoneNumber == _testFixture.GetAdvertisementWithNoZipCode().OriginalPhoneNumber))).Returns(Task.FromResult(_testFixture.GetDealerWithZipCode()));
_testFixture.MongoRepository.Setup(x => x.FindAsync(Builders<Dealer>.Filter.ElemMatch(y => y.Phones, z => z.PhoneNumber == _testFixture.GetAdvertisementWithNoZipCode().OriginalPhoneNumber))).ReturnsAsync(_testFixture.GetDealerWithZipCode());
```

**Return Objects Tried**

```
public IList<Dealer> GetDealerWithZipCode()
{
    return new List<Dealer>
    {
        new Dealer
        {
            Active = true,
            DealerName = "City Chevrolet",
            Phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone
                {
                    PhoneNumber = "4033809999"
                }
            },
            MasterCode = "CHEV01",
            RevisionDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    };
}

public async Task<IList<Dealer>> GetDealerWithZipCode()
{
    return await Task.Run(() => new List<Dealer>
    {
        new Dealer
        {
            Active = true,
            DealerName = "City Chevrolet",
            Phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone
                {
                    PhoneNumber = "4033809999"
                }
            },
            MasterCode = "CHEV01",
            RevisionDate = DateTime.UtcNow
        }
    });
}
```

**Exception**

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
     at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
     at Domain.Advertisement.Service.BackgroundProcessors.ZipCodeAndLocationProcessor.<DealerZipCodeAndLocation>d__5.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\Vader\AdSvc\domain\domain.advertisement.service\BackgroundProcessors\ZipCodeAndLocationProcessor.cs:line 60
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at Domain.Advertisement.Service.BackgroundProcessors.ZipCodeAndLocationProcessor.<ProcessVehicleAdvertisementLocation>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\Vader\AdSvc\domain\domain.advertisement.service\BackgroundProcessors\ZipCodeAndLocationProcessor.cs:line 42
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
     at Domain.Advertisement.Service.Tests.Processors.ZipCodeAndLocation.ZipCodeAndLocationProcessorFacts.<ProcessVehicleAdvertisementLocation_AdLineHasEmptyZipCodePhoneMatchesDealer_GeocodeIsAddedToAdvertisement>d__3.MoveNext() in C:\Repos\Vader\AdSvc\tests\domain.advertisement.service.tests\Processors\ZipCodeAndLocation\ZipCodeAndLocationProcessorFacts.cs:line 47
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Xunit.Sdk.TestInvoker`1.<>c__DisplayClass48_1.<<InvokeTestMethodAsync>b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Xunit.Sdk.ExecutionTimer.<AggregateAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
     at Xunit.Sdk.ExceptionAggregator.<RunAsync>d__9.MoveNext()
```

When I debug I am getting an ArgumentNullException because I am not getting my return object. I know I have an issue in my setup, but I am struggling to figure out where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the method under test which I assume is `DealerZipCodeAndLocation` you should be able to setup the repository mock as follows

```
_testFixture.MongoRepository
    .Setup(_ => _.FindAsync(It.IsAny<FilterDefinition<Dealer>>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(_testFixture.GetDealerWithZipCode());
```

this should simplify the expectations for the test assuming

```
Task<IList<T>> FindAsync<T>(FilterDefinition<T> t) where T : IMongoModel
```

belongs to the repository interface provided by `_testFixture.MongoRepository`, and should safely exercise the method under test to the line

```
if (matchingDealer.Geocode == null) {
    //...
```

Where you would also need to make sure that the other dependencies like the logger and geo location cache are properly mocked for the test to be exercised as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much.  It was an issue that the signature was not matching for Moq to resolve it.  Instead of using Linq or Builders<T>.Filter in the Moq setup, I needed to pass the resulting FilterDefinition.  Completely did not dawn on me.